# Symfony + Vue.js

Tags: vue.js, symfony

Хочу написать REST API приложение используя Symfony и Vue.js, но не могу понять с чего начать и как их связать? Получается в корневой директории нужно создать два проекта(один симфони другой вью)? Как построить роутинг? И как это все потом запускать т.к. симфони сервер мы запускаем отдельно, а вью запускаем отдельно (npm run serve)?

Answer (score 2):

Посмотри модель SPA приложений, они же одностраничные приложения. Vue выступит в роли фронта, а Symfony бэкенд - тут реализуешь rest api.

В итоге:

1. отрисовываешь морду на Vue
2. Vue отправляет запрос к Symfony
3. Symfony отдает данные
4. Vue рендерит

По поводу структуры - зависит от твоей задачи. Если потестить/поиграться, можешь смело пихать всё в одном месте и запускать по очереди (тут сможешь сделать сборщик, который запустит всё сам последовательно). Если это какой-то более серьезный проект, то лучше разделить: фронт на основном домене, а бек где-нибудь на поддомене или другом домене, чтобы находились в разных местах.

[Пример](https://github.com/Clasen00/simple-spa) (не мой)

Comment: Создал два проекта в одной корневой директории. Теперь пытаюсь послать запрос на стороне vue с помощью axios, но в ответ получаю `error  'axios' is not defined  no-undef` ( Vue изучаю недавно и axios запрос отправляю первый раз

Comment: Значит axios не обозначен... Ты его установил через консоль, далее в Vue создаешь **компонент**, в нем прописываешь **метод** в котором указан запрос к апи, создаешь **экземпляр** с отображением твоих данных. Опционально: добавить в компонент такой метод  `created() {  this.твойМетодЗапроса(); 
 },` - здесь явно укажешь, что при создании экземпляра выполнить метод запроса.
[Дока с примерами](https://ru.vuejs.org/v2/cookbook/using-axios-to-consume-apis.html)